# Cast(GetDate() as int) comes out incorrect after noon

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So is this supposed to happen? or is something wrong with my query.
if I run the following query

`select getdate() as [Date], 
CAST(getdate() as date) as [Time],
CAST(getdate() as INT) as INT, 
Cast(CAST(cast(getdate() as int) as DATETime) as Date) as finish`

If I run this at 11:55:00 AM [finish] returns the correct date.
If I run the query at 12:10:00 PM [finish] returns tomorrows date.
I tried to search for this and couldn't find anything so sorry if its been noted before.
I'm trying to group by Date but I don't want to group by time also, that is why I am doing the conversions.
Running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Don't convert it to an `INT` - that's nonsensical.  Use `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`

Comment: I agree converting from datetime to int then back to date is tedious, this is how the database was already setup.  I guess the way I think of time is 12:00:01 AM is start of a day and 11:59:59 PM is end of the day.

Comment: @Luaan  `12:10:00 AM` is in the middle of the night.  `12:10:00 PM` is just after noon.  Using `12:10:00` as a literal in a cast/convert to a time value will get you 10 minutes past midday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that (if you absolutely have to do these converts, I know it used to be required long ago) that you are using `int` instead of `float` and getting rounding on your converted values:

```
select getdate() as [Date]
    ,CAST(getdate() as date) as [Time]
    ,CAST(getdate() as INT) as INT
    ,Cast(CAST(cast(getdate() as int) as DATETime) as Date) as finishInt
    ,CAST(getdate() as float) as FLOAT
    ,Cast(CAST(cast(getdate() as float) as DATETime) as Date) as finishFloat
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+------------+-------+------------+------------------+-------------+
|          Date           |    Time    |  INT  | finishInt  |      FLOAT       | finishFloat |
+-------------------------+------------+-------+------------+------------------+-------------+
| 2017-02-07 16:47:59.823 | 2017-02-07 | 42772 | 2017-02-08 | 42771.6999979552 | 2017-02-07  |
+-------------------------+------------+-------+------------+------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me realize what was going on!